# iOS popup close button label: "OK" or "Okay"?

Tags: iphone, ios, button, popup, alert

I'm working on an iPhone app with custom popup alerts. In the design these alerts all have "Cancel" buttons, but since there is nothing to cancel in these cases, I want to change them to "Okay" buttons.

My question is this: What are the Apple guidelines regarding these button labels? Should it be "Okay" (which is my personal preference), or should it be "OK" (which I don't like because it looks like teen-text-speak or the state abbreviation for Oklahoma).

Comment: You sure won't get rejected for it, even if you put a completely different word there - presuming the word represented what that button does. I prefer to use 'Okay' for mine.

Comment: Okay, OK, and O.K. are all acceptable spellings of the word.But OK is more common.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK is what Apple uses for settings and their iPhone apps.

Answer (score 6):

Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/alerts/) say to use "OK", so its best to stick with that for consistency:

> Use OK for simple acceptance. Avoid using Yes or No.

They have a few additional helpful tips on the subject:

> **Give alert buttons succinct, logical titles.** The best button titles consist of one or two words that describe the result of selecting the button. As with all button titles, use title-style capitalization and no ending punctuation. To the extent possible, use verbs and verb phrases that relate directly to the alert title and message—for example, View All, Reply, or Ignore.